# Xcode derived data path error

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I'm getting this error after adding a WatchKit extension to my app:

```
PBXCp DerivedData/App/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/appwatch.app DerivedData/App/Build/Products/Debug/App.app/Watch/appwatch.app
    cd /Users/User/Documents/App-watchapp
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/User/Documents/App-watchapp/DerivedData/App/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/appwatch.app /Users/User/Documents/App-watchapp/DerivedData/App/Build/Products/Debug/App.app/Watch

error: /Users/User/Documents/App-watchapp/DerivedData/App/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/appwatch.app: No such file or directory
```

I've tried changing the path of the derived data folder, cleaning, deleting then re-adding the extension, and nothing has worked.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Did you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Window > Projects.
2. Delete the derived data for the project that is causing this error.
3. Clean.
4. Try running the project again.

Comment: I have tried that without success. The file path it is trying to reach has 'Debug-watchsimulator' in it, but the actual folder name is just Debug. Maybe that's the problem, but how would I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you build with xcode or xcodebuild cli?
With xcodebuild I get almost the same error.
But when I exchange CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR with SYMROOT the error is gone and I can build and archive.